# Referring to another element in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to design an XML document structure for my application.

I want to store a list of holes like following

```
<Holes>
 <Hole id='1' dia='0.1' depth='2'/>
 <Hole id='2' dia='0.2' depth='1.67'/>
 <Hole id='3' dia='0.3' depth='0.44'/>
</Holes>
```

In another part of my document I want to refer to a hole by its id. e.g.

```
<Drill useHoleWithId='1'/>
```

When my code finds above <Drill> element I want it to retrieve the values of 'dia' and 'depth' attributes in the <Hole> element that has id='1'.

Of course I can search for a <Hole> element with id equal to the  value of 'useHoleWithId' and then get the values of the attributes, but I thought maybe there's a better way to do this using some XML trick. Is there?

PS - Though I don't have any idea about them, may be any of XPath, XLink, XQuery or XPointer could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath is certainly one way to do it. An Xpath query to find the hold with id 1 would be something like `Holes/Hole[@id="1"]`

Answer (score 3):

**There is a standard XPath function to reference elements by their "id" attribute**.

**From the [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-id) spec**.:

The **[`id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-id)** function function selects elements by their unique `ID` (see [5.2.1 Unique IDs]). When the argument to `id` is of type `node-set`, then the result is the union of the result of applying `id` to the `string-value` of each of the nodes in the argument `node-set`. When the argument to `id` is of any other type, the argument is converted to a `string` as if by a call to the `string function`; the `string` is split into a `whitespace-separated list of tokens` (`whitespace` is any sequence of characters matching the production `S`); the result is a `node-set` containing the elements in the same `document` as the `context node` that have a `unique ID` equal to any of the tokens in the list.

- `id("foo")` selects the element with unique `ID` foo
- `id("foo")/child::para[position()=5]` selects the fifth para child of the
  element with unique `ID` foo

**Another, more generic way of referring to nodes (not only elements) is possible in [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)**. The **[`<xsl:key/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)** instruction and the XSLT **[`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key)** function are specifically designed for this purpose.

**For example**, suppose a document contains bibliographic references in the form XSLT, and there is a separate XML document bib.xml containing a bibliographic database with entries in the form:

```
<entry name="XSLT">...</entry>
```

**Then the stylesheet could use the following to transform the bibref elements**:

```
<xsl:key name="bib" match="entry" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="bibref">
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="document('bib.xml')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bib',$name)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Do note**, that keys in XSLT overcome the following limitations of the `id()` function:

- ID attributes must be declared as
  such in the DTD. If an ID attribute
  is declared as an ID attribute only
  in the external DTD subset, then it
  will be recognized as an ID attribute
  only if the XML processor reads the
  external DTD subset. However, XML
  does not require XML processors to
  read the external DTD, and they may
  well choose not to do so, especially
  if the document is declared
  `standalone="yes"`.
- A document can contain only a single
  set of unique IDs. There cannot be
  separate independent sets of unique
  IDs.
- The ID of an element can only be
  specified in an attribute; it cannot
  be specified by the content of the
  element, or by a child element.
- An ID is constrained to be an XML
  name. For example, it cannot contain
  spaces.
- An element can have at most one ID.
- At most one element can have a
  particular ID.

Because of these limitations XML documents sometimes contain a cross-reference structure that is not explicitly declared by ID/IDREF/IDREFS attributes.

Answer (score 1):

XML is an inert view on the data. You already *have* created your reference with "useHoleWithId". How you interpret and act upon that to get that `<hole>` element is up to your implementation, and certainly xpath (xslt to change the document is just implementing xpath to do this) is a strong way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may transform it:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="my/Drill">
   <xsl:variable name="drillid"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="@useHoleWithId"/>
   </xsl:variable> 
   <Drill>
    <xsl:attribute name="diameter">
     <xsl:value-of select="/my/Holes/Hole[@id=$drillid]/@dia"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="useid">
     <xsl:value-of select="$drillid"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </Drill>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

so that `Hole`'s attribute will appear in `Drill` tags