# Replace attribute values in custom sections in same web.config file

Tags: c#, web-config, transform

In same web.config file i got two custom sections like

```
<SectionOne>
    <Element1 value="value1" />
    <Element2 value="value2" />
</SectionOne>

<SectionTwo>
    <items>
        <item key="value1" ... />
        <item key="value2" ... />
    </items>
</SectionTwo>
```

and i would like to use once defined values in SectionOne, and put them in SectionTwo, each one in its place... and other places in web.config file.

"value1" from SectionOne goes to "value1" in SectionTwo and so on...

Is it possible to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464853/referring-to-another-element-in-xml

Comment: like <item key="SectionOne/Element1[@path]" ... /> ?? it does not works... that is another case